# createReturnOrder

Tags: connect-api

Hi i'm writing in Apex a code that must call to [this method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ReturnOrder_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ReturnOrder_createReturnOrder_1). I don't know how i can call it, i try with

```apex
ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation idReturnOrder = new ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation();
idReturnOrder.createReturnOrder(generateReturnOrder);
```

I can't make the call to the method, I have tried different ways and I always get an error similar to this one

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createReturnOrder(ConnectApi.ReturnOrderInputRepresentation) from the type ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation (166:31)

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? Are you getting an error message, is the code saving, etc? You can [edit] your question to add any relevant errors or behavior.

Comment: when I said dont work, I meant I couldn't get it to work. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently trying to call a method that exists within the `ReturnOrder` class under the `ConnectApi` namespace through your variable `idReturnOrder`. The method isn't defined in that variable which is why you get the message that the method doesn't exist.

The way to verify what's expected is to take a look at what the parent pages are along with the signature section for the method in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ReturnOrder_static_methods.htm#:%7E:text=No-,Signature,-public%20static%20ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation). For this, it shows the document organization (on left sidebar) is:

- ConnectApi Namespace

  - ReturnOrder Class

    - ReturnOrder Methods

      - createReturnOrder(returnOrderInput)

While the signature for the method shows:

```apex
public static ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation createReturnOrder(ConnectApi.ReturnOrderInputRepresentation returnOrderInput)
```

You'll note the following:

- It's under `ConnectApi` and `ReturnOrder` class
- It returns a value of type `ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation`
- It's static
- It expects one parameter of type `ConnectApi.ReturnOrderInputRepresentation`

You're currently passing in `generateReturnOrder` which I'll assume is `ConnectApi.ReturnOrderInputRepresentation` , but you're not storing the return value and you're not calling the method from where it's located:

```apex
ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation idReturnOrder = new ConnectApi.ReturnOrderOutputRepresentation();
//store return value from calling method
//call method within ConnectApi and ReturnOrder class
idReturnOrder = ConnectApi.ReturnOrder.createReturnOrder(generateReturnOrder);
```

Comment: Thanks, it´s very useful

Comment: Great. FYI - for [this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), upvotes and accepting answers is the way we designate good answers or those that solve the question.

Comment: I dont know why do you edit my post. when you post, i posted first the solution

Comment: The question body is for the question only. The site already has separate mechanisms/posts for questions & answers. If you had the answer first/already, please post an *answer* on your own question (don't add it to the question) and accept that answer. You can refer to [Can I answer my own question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for steps/explanation on how to do so.

Comment: Ok sorry, i'm newbie and idk

Comment: No need to apologize - I'm just trying to help point out there's separate things (questions & answers) on this site. Answering your own question is great - there's nothing wrong with it and I've done it plenty of times when I've solved something on my own. I just had no clue you answered it yourself as I wouldn't expect an answer within a question once you edited it - only noticed today on re-read.